# How do I get my grid to do fixed width on the first column and arbitrary length on the second but align properly?

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, multiple-columns

I have a Grid like so:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sync:SyncObject}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsKept}" Style="{DynamicResource IsKeptStyle}" Width="50" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

However, when I run the window, column 1 (the second column) is randomly spaced (something like this):

```
[toggle]                             Name
[toggle]                           Name
[toggle]                              Name
```

Why? What am I doing wrong? Doesn't it makes sense that it should be:

```
[toggle]    Name
[toggle]    Name
[toggle]    Name
```

Since the column has a fixed width?

Here is the style for the toggle:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" x:Key="IsKeptStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Replace"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Keep"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

EDIT:
It seems that removing the ListBox causes it to align properly, but I need the listbox. Any ideas?

Comment: I have to wonder if those spaces aren't coming from the string value you're populating the `TextBlock` with perhaps as opposed to the `TextBlock` itself.

Comment: I don't think so because if I make column 0's width auto instead of 70  the "Name" text lines up right next to the toggle like you would expect. [toggle]Name

Comment: Throw ShowGridLines="True" on your grid and see where your boundaries actually are, the way you have it should be fine so there's got to be something else awry.

Comment: The grid lines show faulty as well. The "Name" text is left aligned to column 1, but column 0 seems to have a variable width.

Comment: Just to try, on your `TextBlock` try setting `TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`

Comment: That didn't work either. Hmmm...

Comment: @PriceJones yeh wasn't really expecting it too. Can't reproduce this issue. Can you actually reproduce this in a new project. It could be some app level style's or something screwing it up?

Comment: Show your "IsKeptStyle" template for your `ToggleButton` or omit it to see if that's your culprit.

Comment: I ran it without the style but it continues to have the same problem.

Comment: Sounds like much more would need to be seen to troubleshoot this one, I'd be looking at inherited styles and the likes from further up the tree. Anything that could interact with the elements used that could cause your trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slept on it. This is the solution:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sync:SyncObject}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ShowGridLines="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ShowGridLines="True">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsKept}" Style="{DynamicResource IsKeptStyle}" Width="50" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </Grid>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Instead of stuffing everything into one grid with two rows and letting the rows do all the work of sorting out the column spacing (i.e. `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"`), I created a grid with two rows, but row one is a grid that handles the column spacing.